# How to frequency of consecutive rows with the same number for several columns

Tags: r

I have a dataset as follows:

```
structure(list(chr = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1), leftPos = c(240000, 1080000, 1200000, 1320000, 
1440000, 1800000, 2400000, 2520000, 3120000, 3360000, 3480000, 
3600000, 3720000, 4200000, 4560000, 4920000, 5040000, 5160000, 
5280000, 6e+06), chr.1 = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), leftPos.1 = c(240000, 1080000, 1200000, 
1320000, 1440000, 1800000, 2400000, 2520000, 3120000, 3360000, 
3480000, 3600000, 3720000, 4200000, 4560000, 4920000, 5040000, 
5160000, 5280000, 6e+06), ASample = c(0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), Sample1 = c(0, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1), Sample2 = c(0, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1), Sample3 = c(0, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1), Sample4 = c(0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1), Sample5 = c(0, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1), Sample6 = c(0, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1), Sample7 = c(0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1), Sample8 = c(0, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1), Sample9 = c(0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1), Sample10 = c(0, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1), Sample11 = c(0, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1), Sample12 = c(0, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1), Sample13 = c(0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), Sample14 = c(0, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1), Sample15 = c(0, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1)), .Names = c("chr", 
"leftPos", "chr.1", "leftPos.1", "Sample1", 
"Sample2", 
"Sample3", "Sample4", 
"Sample5", "Sample6", 
"Sample7", "Sample8", 
"Sample9", "Sample10", 
"Sample11", "Sample12", 
"Sample13", "Sample14", 
"Sample15"), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")
```

I need to count the number of rows per column where there is more than one of the same 1 or -1

I would like to be able to count the number of consecutive rows for each column, grouped by chr, that have three consecutive 1 or -1 within a chromosome (column called `chr`).

The ideal output would be something like (not taken from the dput data above)

```
chr numberOfConsecutive1s FreqSample1  FreqSample2  FreqSample3 etc
1          2                3           2               14
1          3                5           2               2
1          4                5           0               6
1          5                4           3               5
1          6                3           0               3
1          7                7           5               7
1          8                5           0               2
1          9                54          2               6
1          10               34          77              7
2          2                6           4               2
2          3                23          34              34
2          4                5           37              2
2          5                55          24              22
2          6                2           0               11
2          7                3           14              5
2          8                2           5               77
2          9                5           23              34
2          10               5           11              34
3          1                32          0               2
```

So far I have tried the following which simply converts non consecutive 1s into 0s so I am left with the consecutive 1s only. I don't know how to count them up as per the desired output.

```
dx<-DAT_list2res
f0 <- function( colNr, dx )
{
  col <- dx[,colNr]
  n1 <- which( col == 1 )            # The `1`-rows.
  d0 <- which( diff(col) == 0 )      # Consecutive entries are equal.
  dc0 <- which( diff(dx[,1]) == 0 )  # Same chromosome.
  m <- intersect( n1-1, intersect( d0, dc0 ) )
  return ( setdiff( 1:nrow(dx), union(m,m+1) ) )
}
g <- function( dx )
{
  for ( i in 3:ncol(dx) ) { dx[f0(i,dx),i] <- 0 }  
  return ( dx )
}
dx<-g(dx)
```

***EDIT***

I also tried this as suggested by bramtayl:

```
result = 
  consecFreq %>%
  select(-chr) %>%
  gather(variable, chr,  5:190) %>%
  group_by(variable) %>%
  mutate(ID = 
           chr %>%
           lag %>%
           `!=`(chr) %>%
           plyr::mapvalues(NA, FALSE) %>%
           cumsum) %>%
  count(variable, chr, ID) %>%
  rename(numberOfConsecutive1s = n) %>%
  count(variable, chr, numberOfConsecutive1s) %>%
  spread(variable, n, fill = 0)
```

but it gives me an 'index out of bounds' error. If I ignore the spread line I get an odd output as well so I'm not sure this is the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**REVISED**

Based on clarifications, this approach uses the `rle` function for each chromosome to find runs of consecutive 1's or -1's and then `table` to count the number of runs for each value. This gives `NA` for samples which have no counts for a particular value so the last line of the code converts the `NA's` to `0's` if this is helpful.  Finally there seems to be a problem with your `structure` input in that `Cytospongex10_SLX.9395.FastSeqK.fq.gz.res` is missing from the `.Names` section of `structure`.  This causes all the column names to be shifted and the last column name to be `NA` which can cause problems in the execution.

The code below assigns the correct names to the input data (in `data.frame` `df`) and then calculates the frequencies as described above.

```
    colnames(data) <- c("chr", 
                    "leftPos", "chr.1", "leftPos.1", "Cytospongex10_SLX.9395.FastSeqK.fq.gz.res", "Sample1", 
                    "Sample2", 
                    "Sample3", "Sample4", 
                    "Sample5", "Sample6", 
                    "Sample7", "Sample8", 
                    "Sample9", "Sample10", 
                    "Sample11", "Sample12", 
                    "Sample13", "Sample14", 
                    "Sample15")

 chr_labels <- sort(unique(data$chr))
 sampl_freqs <- data.frame(chr=1,  numberOfConsecutive1s=1, count=0)

for( sampl in colnames(data)[-(1:5)]) {
  freqs <- data.frame()
  for( chr in chr_labels )  {
     runs  <-  rle(data[data$chr == chr,sampl]) 
     freqs_chr <- data.frame(chr=chr, table(runs$length[runs$values %in% c(-1,1)], dnn = "numberOfConsecutive1s") )
     freqs <- rbind(freqs, freqs_chr)
   }
  sampl_freqs <- merge.data.frame(sampl_freqs, freqs, by = c("chr","numberOfConsecutive1s"), all=TRUE)
  colnames(sampl_freqs) <- c(head(colnames(sampl_freqs),-1),paste("Freq",sampl,sep=""))
}
# clean up from sampl_freqs definition
 sampl_freqs <- sampl_freqs[,-3]
 #  To convert NA's to 0
 sampl_freqs <- data.frame(sampl_freqs[,1:2], sapply(sampl_freqs[,-(1:2)], function(x) ifelse(is.na(x), 0, x)))
```

Similar to above, but uses `dplyr`

```
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)

df <- melt(data[,-(2:5)], id.vars="chr",  variable.name="sample")
sampl_freqs <- df %>% group_by(sample, chr )   %>%
 do(data.frame(unclass(rle(.$value))) %>%
      filter(values %in% c(-1,1)) ) %>%
 group_by(sample, chr, lengths) %>%
  summarize(Freq = n() ) %>%
 dcast( chr + lengths ~ sample, value.var = "Freq" ) 
sampl_freqs <- with(sampl_freqs,data.frame( chr, numberOfConsecutive1s = lengths , 
                                            sapply(sampl_freqs[,-(1:2)], function(x) ifelse(is.na(x), 0, x))))
```

Comment: Not bad but the chromosome numbers don't seem to be there they give me a mixture of -1 and 0 and 1 for some reason rather than the actual chromosome number 1 to 22. Hang on...

Comment: No the actual chromosome number doesn't seem to be the chromosome in my whole dataset- it gives me -1,0 and 1. in my dataset chr is the first column so Im not sure how this is coming up with these values

Comment: The first column in your data frame, labels chr, contains only 0"s and 1's .  Are these the chromosome numbers?  Also, is the criteria 3 consecutive 1's on with the same chr column number?  If so, I don't see any instances of this in your data.  Could you point out which sample sets contains an example of this?   Thanks.

Comment: Yes labels chr is chromosome number and I appreciate that they are not 1 to 22 although it still doesn't explain why Im getting -1 0 and 1 in that column in the result. The criteria is a frequency of the number of consecutive rows which are either 1 or -1 within a chr per sample. There are examples of two and three consecutive 1s (but no -1s) in the data.

Comment: Your second answer worked perfectly. Exactly what I wanted. Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

min_chunk_length = 1

result = 
  data %>%
  rename(chromosome = chr) %>%
  select(chromosome, Sample1:Sample15) %>%
  gather(sample, value, Sample1:Sample15) %>%
  group_by(chromosome, sample) %>%
  mutate(non_zero = value %in% c(1, -1),
         chunk_ID = 
           non_zero %>%
           lag %>%
           `!=`(non_zero) %>%
           plyr::mapvalues(NA, FALSE) %>%
           cumsum) %>%
  filter(non_zero = TRUE) %>%
  group_by(chromosome, sample, chunk_ID) %>%
  mutate(length_of_chunk = n()) %>%
  filter(length_of_chunk > min_chunk_length) %>%
  count(chromosome, sample) %>%
  spread(sample, n, fill = 0)
```

Comment: OK looks promising although one problem I have is that my Samples are not always consecutively namedand can have random names. To incorporate this into the gather statement what do I do. I tried st<-colnames(dx[3])
en<-colnames(dx[ncol(dx)-100])  with  gather(variable, chr, st:en) but got the error Error in st:en : NA/NaN argument

Comment: Ok so I put just the column numbers in and it gets as far as the spread statement and then I get 'index out of bounds ' error. Any idea why? It seems to run ok up to that point

Comment: I don't know my code worked for me with your example data

Comment: Just tried it again with the data as posted and the code as posted. I still get the same error. My dplyr is version 0.3.0.2 and tidyr is 0.1

Comment: I have dplyr 0.4.3 and tidyr 0.3.1! I've added a select statement so you can select whatever columns you want to do this analysis on.

Comment: I've updated the versions tho when I run the code it says 'object chr not found'. The column chr is definitely there in the dataframe and I have called the dataframe data

Comment: OK so if I ignore the select statement and instead use gather to specify the columns as follows gather(variable, value, 3:150) then I get one column with each row showing the chromosome (22 rows) then one column with numberOfConsecutive1s which looks as though it is giving the total for all samples per chromosome and then column full of 1s for each sample

Comment: Sorry, when I made the edit I accidentally changed one line. It should be gather(variable, chr, 3:150)

Comment: I changed it already as I thought thats what had happened. However the comment above from me still stands. I would like to get numberOfConsecutive1s per sample per chromosome but at the moment it is giving it to me as a separate column per chromosome and filling all the sample columns with 1s

Comment: Ok, I think I completely misunderstood your question. See the updated code

Comment: Also, I've changed it so that you can change your minimum desired chunk length

Comment: OK. Although I now get exactly the same results for each sample per chromosome which shouldnt be the case

Comment: I don't...not with your example data